# CSS padding beginner stuff

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding the material provided here: [w3schools.com code example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headings)

According to the code :

```
th,td
{
padding:5px;
}
```

also, according to their explanation here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp

padding:10px means all four paddings are 10px

Then why on the live code the executed script shows : 20-22px from the left and right for TH elements??

Comment: Can you post the CSS to the live code? Maybe you have another selector affecting the elements?

Comment: Use firebug or other inspect tool on the TH element to see what style might override the padding.

Comment: Here is the URL: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headings

Comment: I dont see 20-22... http://puu.sh/7Gaiq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables scale proportionally to their width. So, when the `table` tag has a `style="width:300px"` attribute, the table is stretched and the columns are larger. When you take it out, however, the table compresses so that the columns have no extra width. What looks like padding there is actually just extra width of the `th` and `td` elements.

I think you would find it easier to use [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) or something else as a resource, w3schools through me off track enough times when I was learning. Most of the time w3schools doesn't explain things very well, and that width inline style was easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

The short hand for padding all sides is one number.

```
padding: 10px;
```

this is equivalent to

```
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

which is top, right, bottom, left - clockwise order.

or....

```
padding 10px 10px;
```

which is shorthand for top and bottom & left and right...

But you also have to keep in mind that browsers have their own default styles that are applied and can give certain elements padding, margin, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the width set on the table. It influences the cell width, in this case the TH elements. The padding is 5px but due to the set width it grows the cells.

You can though make the cells width to be distributed evenly when the table has set an inline width style. This way the padding of px is applied but the width is set for each cell to 100px. 300px (table width) / 3 (cols length)

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This is a neat way to have evenly width columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/8tLXf/10/